# I Can't build buildozer for android

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to create an APK using Kivy and Buildozer. I'm doing the same as in the tutorial at http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html but i have errors, and i don't understand how to fix them. Please help.
This is my error log:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/oleg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/oleg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/ant/build.xml:655: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/oleg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/build-tools/19.1.0/aidl": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
    at com.android.ant.AidlExecTask$AidlProcessor.process(AidlExecTask.java:102)
    at com.android.ant.MultiFilesTask.processFiles(MultiFilesTask.java:131)
    at com.android.ant.AidlExecTask.execute(AidlExecTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:120)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 48 more

Total time: 1 second
o
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/syslog.so
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/config/Setup
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/config/config.c
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/config/config.c.in
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/config/Setup.local
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/config/Setup.config
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/myapp/private/lib/python2.7/config/install-sh
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/app/sitecustomize.pyo
assets/private.mp3: /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/app/main.pyo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 508, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 357, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python build.py --name 'first app' --version 1.0 --package org.test.myapp --private /home/oleg/Desktop/lol/.buildozer/android/app --sdk 14 --minsdk 8 --orientation landscape debug
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: may take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kivy-users/I7peZkEBdH0/ILgb2Pn2FdsJ)

Comment: It doesn't helps ((((

Comment: have you checked that that file actually exists in your build directory? It seems that from those relevant discussions, it might be down to 32/64 bit version discrepancies, file permissions or that file actually doesn't exist in build folder <-- in last case, you may just copy the file to the build folder and try again

Comment: although unlikely, but are you sure you have all dependencies installed properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it! I saw a few instructions and specific installation of some packages for use it on Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit).
This is my full steps:

```
apt-get install python-pip
pip install --upgrade buildozer

apt-get install python2.7-dev
pip install --upgrade cython

dpkg --add-architecture i386

apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential ccache git lib32z1 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 python2.7 openjdk-7-jdk unzip zlib1g-dev zlib1g:i386

apt-get install python-kivy
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case the accepted answer did not work what I eventually had to do was

```
pip uninstall buildozer
rm -rf ~/.buildozer
pip install buildozer
buildozer android debug
```

When you start building the project this time buildozer will have to go download ANT, SDK, NDK
then I had to update the SDK as done [here](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/146)

to summarize

1. run buildozer's SDK manager using

   `~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-*/tools/android`

   Where the asterisk is either 20 or 21 use tab completion to find out
2. update/install build tools to the desired level (at least 20)